# Why PL/Ruby function is so slow and cannot be canceled?

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I managed to install PL/Ruby by following instruction from here [PL/Ruby](https://github.com/Absolight/postgresql-plruby/tree/fixup-9-3) on Postgresql 9.3, OSX 10.10. However I tried to create a function:

```
  CREATE FUNCTION ruby_max2(x int4, y int4) RETURNS int4 AS '
    return x > y ? x : y
 ' LANGUAGE 'plruby';
```

And call the function I had created:

```
 SELECT ruby_max2(7,8);
```

But there is no result, the query keep going and cannot be canceled (even I cannot kill the process). What did I miss?

Here is my [gdb output](http://pastebin.com/Yk0GiA3X)

Here is my [pg_log](http://pastebin.com/ZgM02HqK)

Comment: At a guess, something's wrong with the extension. For details I'd probably need to see a backtrace - use `select pg_backend_pid()` to get the process ID before running the function then once it's running attach a debugger to it and get a backtrace.

Comment: Unfortunately the binaries are stripped and lack external symbols, but the final entry `rb_vm_bugreport` is interesting. It looks like the Ruby VM might be trying to emit a crashdump: http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/vm_dump.c#706 . See if there's more detail in any of the Library paths mentioned in that link, in Console.app logs or in your PostgreSQL server error logs.

Comment: @CraigRinger yeah you are right, it somehow crashed. `rb_vm_bugreport` led me to pg_log and I found `Segmentation Fault`. See my updated question for pg_log output.

Comment: It looks like it crashed when an error/exception thrown by PostgreSQL from within PL/Ruby crashed the Ruby VM. If you were using multiple threads that'd explain it, otherwise hard to say - maybe ask on pgsql-general.